# suppress apache 500 error for "writable by others"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions

I know it sounds crazy, but I do have a reason for doing this. I would like someone else on the same file system to be able to make changes to files, and unfortunately I can not change the group we are involved in. Is there a way to suppress this error message? I have a feeling it can achieved using some directive in a .htaccess file, but that is simply a whim and I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's not a solution for all cases, but your error is probably caused by suExec or suPHP... Maybe you could disable it or use something else ?

Comment: You are correct it seems to be caused by suPHP. Can I disable it at a user level, or is this some change that would have to be made in the global config file?

Comment: You have `allow_file_others_writeable` in the main config ( http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG ) . Don't think there's any config you can do at a lower level, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

you must CHMON the files that gives you this error to 664 or 775. Look into apache server error logs and check the files

Exemple: can be something like this:

[2010-01-05 04:35:51]: error: file is writable by others: (/home/mysite/public_html/index.php)

In this case give 755 to index.php or 644

Answer (score 0):

**In my case help to change super user owner:**

```
chown -R newuser:newuser /dir
```

*and then*

```
chmod 775 test
```