# suphp internal server error 500. file "../index.php" is writeable by others suPHP 0.7.2

Tags: php, visual-web-developer, suphp

I have just uploaded a new website, but I keep showing the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> File "/home/mirahcom/public_html/pay/cdash/login.php" is writeable by others

Does anyone know why this issue occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [suppress apache 500 error for "writable by others"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130197/suppress-apache-500-error-for-writable-by-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever software you used to upload the files likely allows you to set permissions on files and folder. For FTP clients like Filezilla, right click the remote file or directory and select "File permission"

For OWNER, check all boxes, for the other 2 groups, check READ and EXECUTE

Is Linux land, that equates to `chmod 755 ./*` ... full permissions for you (7)
and read (4) + write (1)=(5) for everyone else